# How do I get specific data from Bundle?

Tags: java, android

I am building an app that has multiple fragments and about half of those fragments contain a view that a user can draw lines with a finger (we'll call canvas). What I'm trying to do is to save the lines drawn by the user who then leaves the fragment for another one and draws some lines on the canvas in that fragment and can go back to the previous fragment (the drawing of the second will get saved) where the drawing for that fragment only will show in the canvas. If the user goes back to the second fragment, the drawing for the second fragment only will show. I am using the Parcelable interface.

The problem I have is that the drawing from one fragment will show in a different fragment and any additional lines will show in the first fragment with the original drawing and I don't know how to fix this issue.

**Fragment 1**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

private PaintView paintView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
        paintView = v.findViewById(R.id.paintView1);

//I tried using this if statement to get the specific data
//Same for the other fragment
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("line test")) {
            paintView.setPaths(savedInstanceState.<FingerPath>getParcelableArrayList("chat test"));
        }
    }
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.normal:
            paintView.normal();
            return true;

        case R.id.clear:
            paintView.clear();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("chat test", paintView.getPaths());
}

}
```

**Fragment 2**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class LineLHwFragment extends Fragment {

private PaintView paintView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_line_l_hw, container, false);
        paintView = v.findViewById(R.id.lineLPaintView);

//here's where I try for fragment 2
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("line test")) {
                paintView.setPaths(savedInstanceState.<FingerPath>getParcelableArrayList("line 
test"));
            }
        }
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.normal:
            paintView.normal();
            return true;

        case R.id.clear:
            paintView.clear();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("line test", paintView.getPaths());
}


}
```

**PaintView.java, controls drawing**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.EmbossMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.MaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class PaintView extends View {

public static int BRUSH_SIZE = 10;
public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
public static int DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
private float mX, mY;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private static ArrayList<FingerPath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
private int currentColor;
private int backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
private int strokeWidth;
private boolean emboss;
private boolean blur;
private MaskFilter mEmboss;
private MaskFilter mBlur;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);



public PaintView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);

}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);

    mPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);

    mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] {1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
    mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(5, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

}

public ArrayList getPaths() {
    return paths;

}

public ArrayList setPaths(ArrayList<FingerPath> list) {
    return this.paths = list;
}

public Path getMPath() {
    return mPath;
}

public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
}

public void normal() {
    emboss = false;
    blur = false;
}



public void clear() {
    backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
    paths.clear();
    normal();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

    for (FingerPath fp: paths) {
        mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

        if (fp.emboss)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
        else if (fp.blur)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);

        mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.restore();
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
    mPath = new Path();
    FingerPath fp = new FingerPath(currentColor, emboss, blur, strokeWidth, mPath);
    paths.add(fp);

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x-mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y-mY);

    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchUp() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            touchUp();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

**FingerPath.java, contains Parcelable interface**

```
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class FingerPath implements Parcelable {

public int color;
public boolean emboss;
public boolean blur;
public int strokeWidth;
public Path path;

public FingerPath(int color, boolean emboss, boolean blur, int strokeWidth, Path path) {
    this.color = color;
    this.emboss = emboss;
    this.blur = blur;
    this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    this.path = path;

}



protected FingerPath(Parcel in) {
    color = in.readInt();
    emboss = in.readByte() != 0;
    blur = in.readByte() != 0;
    strokeWidth = in.readInt();

}

public static final Creator<FingerPath> CREATOR = new Creator<FingerPath>() {
    @Override
    public FingerPath createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new FingerPath(in);
    }

    @Override
    public FingerPath[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FingerPath[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(color);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (emboss ? 1 : 0));
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (blur ? 1 : 0));
    parcel.writeInt(strokeWidth);


}




}
```

Comment: Hi! Are you sure you want to use `Serializable`/`Parcelable` for these purposes? These interfaces are limited and you cannot store a lot of data inside of `parcelable`. Maybe to store it in some kind of persistent storage would be better for you? I mean use in-memory + hard drive storages combination.

Comment: Hi. I was previously told that Parcelable would be the way to go for this. I'm new to coding so please bear with me. How would I go about doing that? Many thanks for the comment :)